# Does any browser in iOS and Android allow events to trigger when the application (browser) is inactive/in background?

Tags: javascript, android, ios, dom-events

What I'm wondering is basically what (if any) browsers in iOS and Android allow events to trigger when the browser is inactive/in background/sleeping?

If any: What kind of events will this browser in that OS allow?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, they do not. If you put the browser in the background, it unloads the page to free some memory for other apps.

Answer (score 1):

In Android, you can accomplish this by writing an Activity whose sole UI component is a web view. Your activity receives many lifecycle events automatically (such as focus / loss of focus) and can request to receive more (such as screen-off, screen-on). You can easily pass these events into the underlying webkit's javascript interface.

Answer (score 0):

If you've got a `<video>` or `<audio>` element with a playing media file in iOS Safari, the `ended` event will trigger, even if the browser is not open. This allows you to select a next media file and play it, sorta emulating the native iPod experience.